# How to Use a loop to call up arrays with different names in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I want to assign values to array1,array2,array3.......upto array60.right now i am using following code as i don't know how do do it in one loop ,is there any way to change array name in loop.How to do this in one loop?

```
            while (array[p] != " ")
            {
                array1[p1] = array[p];
                p++;
                p1++;

            }

            while (array[p] != " ")
            {
                array2[p2] = array[p];
                p++;
                p2++;
            }

            while (array[p] != " ")
            {
                array3[p3] = array[p];
                p++;
                p3++;
            }

            while (array[p] != " ")
            {
                array4[p4] = array[p];
                p++;
                p4++;
            }
```

Comment: Put your arrays into an array.

Comment: thank you for your reply @Tom but how do i do indexing of that array,i have total 60 string arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with a 2 dimentional array you can use 2 loops to fill your arrays:

```
int[,] arrays = new int[60,100];
for(int arraynumber = 0; arraynumber < 60; arraynumber++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< 100;i++)
    {
        arrays[arraynumber,i] = arrays[0,i];
    }
}
```

you can also use an array of arrays

Comment: I doubt if *2D array* `int[,] arrays` is a good choice here. What if arrays in the question are of *different* lengths? Jugged array `int[][] arrays` looks far better.

Comment: you should use an array of arrays if the arrays don't have the same size

Comment: I'm not shure, but I think an array of arrays is slower than a 2d array, but I'm realy not shure

Comment: All arrays have same length,i will try your solution @Thomas

Comment: I have no IDE here @ the moment, so maybe there is a sintaxerror

Comment: ohh... now I see you are using strings... you have to replace the int by string

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var sourceArray = new string[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6"};
var destArrays = new string[4,sourceArray.Length];
int innerIndex = 0;
int outerIndex = 0;

while(outerIndex<destArrays.GetLength(0))
{
    while (innerIndex<sourceArray.Length && sourceArray[innerIndex] != " ")
  {
      destArrays[outerIndex,innerIndex] = sourceArray[innerIndex];
      innerIndex++;
  }
  innerIndex = 0;
  outerIndex++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
string[][] arrays = new string[][] { array1, array2, array3 };

foreach (string[] arr in arrays) {
    // do staff here
}
```

Comment: i did't get your code ,how do i change name from array1 to array2 to assign values to arrays

Comment: You don't change it. You list all the arrays in the { } brackets and the outer forech loop goes through all the array you have listed.